# Scheduled Toast Notification UWP

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp

I would like to make a periodic toastnotification.

The code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string TOAST = @"
                        <toast>
                          <visual>
                            <binding template=""ToastTest"">
                              <text>Hello Toast</text>
                            </binding>
                          </visual>
                          <audio src =""ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail"" loop=""true""/>
                        </toast>";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNotification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var when = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(6);
        var offset = new DateTimeOffset(when);

        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(TOAST);
        ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, offset, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 5);
        toast.Id = "IdTostone";
        toast.Tag = "NotificationOne";
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
    }
}
```

An error occurred with the script: incorrect parameter. [image].

Where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `snoozeInterval` of `ScheduledToastNotification` constructor  should have a value in range from 1 minute to 1 hour.

So, simply change the line of code you get exception in into something like this:

```
ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, offset, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5);
```

Comment: But how do you do to create a repetition, for example, every day without a limit of times?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no convenient way to do this. If you need to send a toast every day at the same time, you can schedule a bunch of toast notifications for a month upfront, one for each day: `for(int i=0; i<31; i++)  ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, offset + TimeSpan.FromDays(i));` And then if you need to change the time of the day for all those toasts, you remove them all from the toast schedule using the `ToastNotificationManager` class and create new scheduled toasts with the right time.

Comment: @LightGreen, if you need a more in-depth explanation, you should probably create a separate question.